# Function returning its argument or checking for nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I would like to loop on a vector and filter out all the non-null-pointer elements. I'm looking for either an `std` function that checks for something being a nullptr or an `std` function that actually returns whatever is passed to it (like `std::forward`), since a null pointer would evaluate to `false`.

```
std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    std::is_pointer<ObjectType*>); // This does not compile

std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    std::forward<ObjectType*>); // This does not compile either

std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    static_cast<bool>); // This won't help me :)

std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    [] (const auto a) { return a; } ); // This is awkward
```

Comment: It's `forward` not `forwad` btw.

Comment: You can just write you own `is_null` lambda/functor/function and pass it to `copy_if` instead of defining the lambda at the call site.  This is such a trivial function there is no real reason to have to standardize it.

Comment: @arboreal84 corrected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stuck with the stuff in `std`, you can use `std::remove_copy_if` with `std::logical_not`.

```
std::remove_copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    std::logical_not<ObjectType*>()); // or std::logical_not<> in C++14
```

Or, you can use `remove_copy` passing `nullptr`:

```
std::remove_copy(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    nullptr);
```

If you really like `copy_if`, you can use `not_fn` or `not1` on the `logical_not` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

I do find having `identity` lying around to be useful sometimes:

```
struct identity_t {
  template<class T>
  T operator()(T&& t)const{ return std::forward<T>(t); }
  constexpr identity_t() {}
};
constexpr identity_t identity;
```

(it converts rvalues to copies, for reference lifetime extension)

Mainly I use it when writing functions with optional mappings, like a transform-filter function: `identity` is the default for transform, and `always_true` is the default for filter.

Comment: is this not even a boost function?

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is nothing like this directly in the standard library.</s> Conceptually, the thing you'd want is:

```
std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    bool);
```

assuming you could use type names as factory functions that construct instances of that type. But, that's not a thing you can do in C++. At least directly. We can write that:

```
template <class T>
struct factory {
    template <class... Args>
    T operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

std::copy_if(dynamicObjects.begin(), dynamicObjects.end(),
    std::back_inserter(existingObjects), 
    factory<bool>{});
```

If you don't like typing `{}`s, you could shorten this by making a variable template.

---

That said, the problem with this:

```
[](const auto a) { return a; } ); // This is awkward
```

isn't so much that it's awkward as much as it's inefficient - that's two copies (one in, one out). You'd want:

```
[](const auto& a) { return static_cast<bool>(a); }
```

Or really just force the `bool` conversion earlier:

```
[](bool b){ return b; }
```

Comment: Why not `[](bool b) { return b; }` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed, that's better.

Comment: I particularly try to avoid doing a cast when an implicit conversion will suffice, it's just a bonus that it ultimately came out shorter.